# Do linear motion equations follow from any of the Newton's three laws?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, acceleration

The distance $x$ covers in time $t$ by a body having initial velocity $u$ having a constant acceleration $a$ is given by $x= ut+(1/2)at^2.$ Does this result follow from any of the Newtonian laws? Similarly, are other equations like $v=u+at$ result of these laws. or not?
If they are what are the laws it follows??

Comment: Thats the beauty of physics ,with only three Newton's l laws and four Maxwell's equation you can explain almost all phenomenas you see in daily life

Comment: @Paul unless you live in the jungle, I think you see more QM than CM. Btw, you forgot thermodynamics haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equations that you have quoted are called kinematic equations.
The dictionary definition of kinematics is:

> the branch of mechanics that deals with pure motion, without reference
>   to the masses or forces involved in it

So kinematic equations are not derived from Newton's laws of motion.
They would be correct irrespective of whether or not Newton's laws of motion were correct.

However dynamics

> the branch of mechanics concerned with the motion of bodies under the
>   action of forces

is very much to do with Newton's laws of motion.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by them following Newton's Three Laws. The idea of acceleration comes from the idea that $F=ma$, which is Newton's Second Law and states that equation. This means that an object that has a net force will also have an acceleration and therefore you will use the kinematic equation $\Delta x = v_ot + 1/2at^2$. But if you're wondering where they come from, you can use calculus to derive it.

$$\int a\ dt= at + C = \Delta\ v$$
$$\int at + C\ dt = \int at + v_0\ dt = v_0t  + 1/2at^2 + \Delta x_0$$

But if you haven't learned calculus, draw a velocity time graph that's linear. Start from a number and draw a straight line. Now calculate the formula for area under the velocity-time graph. You'll have a rectangle area plus a triangle area.